# Any hack/workaround to get silverlight with RIA services with VS2010 with .NET 3.5 framework?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Realized that VS2010 Beta2 has separate WCF RIA installation package which only works with .NET framework 4.0. Searching the google did not give me any pointer as of now. Is there anyway to get WCF RIA in VS2010 working with .NET 3.5 as the targeted framework? I am even fine with VS2010 not able to work with .NET 4.0 on that machine if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to know that it is not possible with these versions